# BackboneJS - using keyword this inside view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

If i want to call a function inside Backbone view, i have to call it like this.

`this.functionName()`

If i want to call the same function inside `forEach` Or `jquery's each` function, `this` refers to different context here. So i need to hold view's reference to some other variable and i have to use it something like below.

```
refresh: function () {
   var view = this;

   $("#list").each (function () {
       view.functionName();
   })
}
```

And finally, if i look at my view, i declare like this almost all of my functions. Did anyone find better alternative for this?

Comment: No this is a common practice used and in essence correct because of scoped approach in js. generally var that=this; is used :) Using view as the variable name may confuse !!

Comment: So everyone is doing the same. Holding reference to view on each functions start !!! good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed common in Javascript, by convention they call the variable `that`:

```
var that = this
```

jQuery also has a `proxy()` function which will call a function and set the context variable (`this`) to something you assign: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

So you could do something like this:

```
refresh: function() {

   $("#list").each($.proxy(function() {
       view.functionName()
   }, this))

}
```

But most of the times it is even more unreadable. To be honest I never use `proxy()` and I can't think of a good example of when to use it, but it's nice to know of it's existance, might you ever need it.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using Backbone, you would already have underscore. Using underscore you can specify context for each call.

```
refresh: function() {

   _.each($("#list"), function() {
      this.functionName()
   }, this))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usuals are defining either `var that = this;` or `var self = this;` or `var _this = this;`

The [Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#naming-conventions) which I find very sane advocates the latter. (you may want to scroll a little to find the meat).